# Want to use polymorphism to write C# code

Tags: c#

I want to refactor the code to use polymorphism instead of if-else. I can do it using if .. else. But I want to use polymorphism here.

Can anyone please advise me?

```
public class Calculator
{
    public int Calculate(int a, int b, Operation operation)
    {
        switch(operation)
        {
            case "add":
                return a+b;

            case "subtract": 
                return a-b;

            case "multiply":
                return a*b;

        default: 
            throw new Exception("Unknown Operation Type");
    }
}

public class Operation
{
    public string Type { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Class assignment?

Comment: There is no `if...else` anywhere in the code that you have provided.

Comment: "Use polymorphism instead if-else"? The one has nothing to do with the other. The one is a syntacical thing (if-else), the other a design.

Comment: @DavidHoelzer, Sorry I was mistaken. I was trying to say that I can achieve this using if--else. But I want to use polymorphism here to do. So please advise.

Comment: I'd advise you to start by writing valid C# code.

Comment: You mean something like this? https://dotnetfiddle.net/xEpGOS

Comment: Polymorphism can't be used here. It's a principal of object-oriented programming, which you're not doing.

Comment: @DubDub Sure you can, as Lasse proofes.

Comment: @HimBromBeere I'd argue that it's a concept of **inheritance** and not **polymorphism**. Woul dyou agree?

Comment: @HimBromBeere Scratch that. I stand [corrected](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/polymorphism).

Comment: @HimBromBeere Suppose it should have been more like 'Polymorphism can't be used without an object-oriented approach, which you're not currently doing'

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To my understanding the selection of an operation can be implemented using polymorphism as follows. First, one would define an interface for the operation.

```
public interface IOperation
{
    int Operate(int a, int b);
}
```

Next, one would implement different classes using the same interface as the actual implementations.

```
public class Addition : IOperation
{
    public int Operate(int a, int b){ return a + b; }
}

public class Subtraction : IOperation
{
    public int Operate(int a, int b){ return a - b; }
}

public class Multiplication : IOperation
{
    public int Operate(int a, int b){ return a * b; }
}
```

As this was also done in the initial question, the actual operation could be executed by the following function.

```
public int Calculate(int a, int b, IOperation iOp)
{
    return iOp.Operate(a, b);
}
```

Comment: Just to add to what codor is doing here, this is called strategy pattern just in case someone wants to deep further into what he did.

Answer (score -5):

I think you're asking for something like this. But it's a guess due to limited background info.

```
public int Calculate(int a, int b, Operation operation)
{
  if(operation == "add")
    return Add(a, b);
  if(operation == "sub")
    return Sub(a,b);
  return 0;
}

private int Add(int a, int b) { return a + b; }
```

Comment: Downvote? Care to explain?

Comment: How is this any more polymorph than OPs current code?

Comment: Actually, I want the same functionality of the code using polymorphism. Please do not use if..else.

Comment: @HimBromBeere It's not. OP is apparently struggling with the concepts so I lay little trust in that he actually asks for polymorphism. Just trying to figure out where OP's problem is do help them resolve it and progress.

Comment: @Aayu The concept of polymorphism is that the methods are called the same way but have different parameter signature. There's no direct way to figure out if `int a, int b` is meant to imply addition or subtraction. You'd have to pass a third parameter and then, the concept makes no sense in this case.

Comment: What if you´d have an `abstract` `Compute`-method and two concrete `Add`- and `Subtract`-classes implementing that method, as  Lasse Vågsæther Karlsen suggests. Makes sense, IMHO. Anyway polymorphism doesn´t deal with **different** method-signatures, but with **equal** ones.

Comment: @HimBromBeere As pointed out in my other comment - I'm admittedly mistaken. However, what is it called if not polymorphism then when you have `public void Donkey(int a)` and `public void Donkey(double a)`? I thought **that** was polymorphism...

Comment: I'd call that [Function Overloading](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Function_overloading)

Comment: @KonradViltersten No, that´s not polymorphism, that´s just overloading. The former is something like `virtual void Donkey()` and `override void Donkey()`.